# Can you run apache2 on windows's wsl feature?

Tags: apache2

Can you run apache2 on windows's wsl feature (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS)?

note: I tried to do it, i get this error:

```
lokz@JACK-PC2:~$ sudo service apache2 start
 * Starting Apache httpd web server apache2
(20014)Internal error (specific information not available): 
AH00058: Error retrieving pid file envvars
AH00059: Remove it before continuing if it is corrupted.
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
 *
```

> The Apache error log may have more information.

It doesn't.

Comment: If you want to run services on Ubuntu install virtualbox or vmware player in Windows and install Ubuntu into that. You will have a full fledge Linux though this will also remove the ability to use Windows tool on that instance.

Answer (score 2):

The only other answer to this question at time of writing answer is no longer true, so adding this here for those who are Googling. As of March 2022 both versions of WSL work well with services such as Apache and MySQL - I use them constantly. You'll need to install them first as they don't come installed with the default Ubuntu distro, but a simple

```
sudo apt install apache2 mysql-server
```

Will do the trick. Once Apache is installed you can navigate to http://localhost in your Window browser and see the default Apache page.

***CAVEAT:*** I haven't tried this for anything other than local development. For production servers I would definitely use a full Linux install, or a native Windows based webserver if your environment needs to be Windows.

Answer (score 1):

***From the [WSL FAQ](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/faq#can-i-run-all-linux-apps-in-wsl):***

> #### Can I run ALL Linux apps in WSL?
>
> **No!** WSL is a tool aimed at enabling users who need them to run Bash and core Linux command-line tools on Windows.
>
> WSL does not aim to support GUI desktops or applications (e.g. Gnome,
> KDE, etc.)
>
> Also, even though you will be able to run many popular server
> applications (e.g. Redis), **we do not recommend WSL for hosting
> production services** – Microsoft offers a variety of solutions for
> running production Linux workloads in Azure, Hyper-V, and Docker.

---

Although you *might* be able get Apache working with some research and elbow grease, I think MS's advice is solid.  You might not want to run a web server from a Windows Store app on your Windows desktop.  WSL is just not the right tool for the task.